# Don't understand the link between constructor and object

Tags: java, object, constructor

I'm trying to learn java and and moving along OK but I ran across this example and I don't understand how "tommy" is passed from myPuppy to name. Can someone explain how that works? I don't understand how the 2 are linked.

---

```
public class Puppy {

    public Puppy(String name) {
        // This constructor has one parameter, name.
        System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name ); 
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // Following statement would create an object myPuppy
        Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "tommy" );
    }
}
```

If we compile and run the above program, then it would produce the following result:

Passed Name is :tommy

---

Comment: Why was that unexpected? You've defined a constructor, that takes a string, so when you construct an instance with a string that's what gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not passed from `myPuppy` to `name`. What happens is:

- A new `Puppy` object is created when the `new Puppy(...)` expression is evaluated.
- The constructor is called. Each parameter in the constructor (in this case, `name`) is replaced with the argument that is passed to `new`. In this case `"tommy"`. So inside the constructor, the variable `name` now refers to the string `tommy`.
- Then the new constructed object is assigned to the variable `myPuppy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the Constructor as a function having one parameter which is "name". In the body of this function, you have the console printing statement.

Once you call it in your main program, then a Puppy will be initialized with the name provided, which is "tommy" in here.

Once you have this object initialized, the name will be printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As the name already implies, a constructor *constructs* an object. An object is an instance on a class. In your case `Puppy` is the class you are creating an object of.

In Java a new object is created by the `new` keyword. You can think of the constructor being called like a function when you create a new object of a class.

In this case `new Puppy("tommy")` will pass the constructor a reference to the `String` "tommy" and will assign it to the variable `name`. The `System.out.println(...)` call will then be passed the reference to "tommy" and print it out on the console.